# Hosting a website built with webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix, sdf

I had built a website using Webmatrix 3 and used the '.sdf' database. However, I couldn't use the web deploy technique since my host doesn't allow it.

The files have an extension of '.cshtml'

I've uploaded the files using ftp and when I open the link to those pages, they only show the code like they show when they are opened manually by double clicking on them not even on a localhost.

Is there a way I can host my website with the .sdf database?

Comment: You should ask your host for help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the ASP.NET Web Pages framework (the pages you're talking about '.cshtml') needs your to have the Web Pages framework installed so that they can run.

IIS needs the Web Pages add on to work with the .cshtml files, and to render the HTML using the Razor syntax, that you're trying to tell me. I remember, once I opened the .cshtml page using Opera Web Server, and it gave me the same error since it was not able to render the HTML and thought the code itself was the HTML.

The problem about the .sdf is that you cannot use it. If they don't support Web Deploy, I think they don't support the SQL Server CE database either. This means that you cannot use them.

As, alread told, you can only ask your hosting service provider for help in this scenario. They can guide you further. Or can forward you to some other branch where these services are supported.